# Delete all of type across all indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash to store logs. I'd like to delete all logstash entries of type 'error'. I checked out the Delete by Query API, but I can't seem to figure out how to do what I want in this situation. Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "logstash entries of type 'error'"? Is this an index, a type in an index?

Comment: "error" is a type across multiple logstash indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Logstash indices are named `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` try this:

`DELETE /logstash*/error` or `DELETE /logstash*/_query?q=_type:error`

Just to be on the safe side, make a backup of your data before trying this. In my tests, both those queries deleted only the `error` type under everything `logstash` indices.

Comment: The second query worked for me. `DELETE logstash*/_query?q=_type:error`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to do it manually, there is a command line utility written in python which would delete, close, optimize and disable bloom filter for better performance and resource utilization.

This will enable you to write a cronjob which will do it periodically with no human intervention needed.

The details about curator can be found out at : https://github.com/elasticsearch/curator

For example to delete indices which are older than 90 days use the following command

`$curator delete --older-than 90`